# Remove classes in release flavor

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

My app has an activity that is used only for debugging. It is accessible from the options menu, which has a "debug" item.

This item is hidden in the release build type (it's only accessible in debug build type). So, the debug activity itself (and its classes, xml, etc) is useless in the release build type. Is it possible to remove the associated classes and layout files in that condition?

I've analyzed Proguard if I can configure it to remove only the specified files, but I couldn't find any parameter like "-unkeep" or similar.

Thanks in advance

Iuri

Comment: Put the activity, its manifest entry, and its resources in a `src/debug/` sourceset, instead of `src/main/`. Then, it will only be included in `debug` builds.

Comment: You may need a shell for the activity in the release source set.  The class will presumably be referred to from the main source set so it needs to be accessible in all build variants.  If you figure out how to not refer to the class from main then this concern doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that is ok for me: move the class from the main folder to the debug folder (with all subfolders), and create the same class in the release folder, with empty content. Do the same for XML files, drawables etc.